# How to add items to RecyclerView from EditText, ImageView with onClickListener?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-popupwindow

so I want to make an app, where you can add data such as `Image`, `Video`, `description` and `Title` from `PopupWindow`, then by clicking `AddButton` it will add provided data to `recyclerView`. I know I need to use `notifyItemInserted` but i don't know how. The `Image` will be a thumbnail, `Video` will be not visible, it will work only on the next `fragment` with player (i will do it later).

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77Dqn.png) is a preview of popupWindow and recyclerView behind it.

RecyclerAdapter.kt

```
class RecyclerAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

private var dataList = emptyList<ListData>()

class MyViewHolder(val binding: CardLayoutBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
    return MyViewHolder(CardLayoutBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent,false))
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.binding.tvTitle.text = dataList[position].title
    holder.binding.tvDescription.text = dataList[position].description
    holder.binding.tvThumbnail // what to do next?
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return dataList.size
     }
  }
```

ListData.kt

```
data class ListData(
val id: Int,
val title: String,
val description: String,
val image: ImageView,
val Video: VideoView
)
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private var dialogView: View? = null

private val getPreviewImage = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(), ActivityResultCallback {
    it?.let { uri ->
        dialogView?.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageChange)?.setImageURI(it)
    }?:run {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "URI not present")
    }
})

private val getPreviewVideo = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(), ActivityResultCallback {
it?.let { uri ->
    dialogView?.findViewById<VideoView>(R.id.videoChange)?.setVideoURI(it)
}?: run{
    Log.e("MainActivity", "URI not present")
    }
})

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    supportActionBar?.hide()

    bottomNavigationView.background = null
    bottomNavigationView.menu.findItem(R.id.placeholder).isEnabled = false
    replaceFragment(HomeFragment())

    bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener {
        when (it.itemId) {
            R.id.home -> replaceFragment(HomeFragment())
            R.id.player -> replaceFragment(PlayerFragment())
            R.id.profile -> replaceFragment(ProfileFragment())
            R.id.settings -> replaceFragment(SettingsFragment())
        }
        true
    }

    popupAddButton.setOnClickListener {
        showDialog()
    }
}


private fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
    val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
    transaction.commit()
}
private fun showDialog() { //this is for popupWindow
    dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null)
    val dialog = Dialog(this)
    val titleEditText = dialogView?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.titleEdit) //popUp edit field title
    val descEditText = dialogView?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.description) //popUp edit field description

    dialogView?.addImage?.setOnClickListener {
        getPreviewImage.launch("image/*")

    }
    dialogView?.addVideo?.setOnClickListener {
        getPreviewVideo.launch("video/*")
    }

    dialogView?.addButton?.setOnClickListener {
        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true)
        if (titleEditText?.text?.isEmpty() == true || descEditText?.text?.isEmpty() == true){
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "add required data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
    dialog.setContentView(dialogView!!)
    dialog.show()
   }
}
```

Comment: I’m away from computer right now so I can’t write a proper answer. But I have to mention…don’t store fragment references in properties. If the fragment is recreated, your reference will be broken and the old fragment will be leaked. You should use find by tag each time you need to work with one of them.

Comment: Also, don’t store your lists in the adapter. Keep them in a ViewModel or they’ll be destroyed if the screen rotates or some other config change. Plus it’s bad separation of concerns. And don’t create multiple lists of the same size to hold related information. Make a single list of items that each contain all the related information for a row (using a data class to represent an item).

Comment: @Tenfour04 okey, can you add answer when you will be able to? I'm new in kotlin and android, still learning.

Comment: I can’t get really give a proper answer since your code doesn’t do any of the things I suggested, so I would have to go through all those different subjects. It would take a very long time to explain everything and it’s all information that’s available in tutorials on the official Android documentation site so I’d just be duplicating their work. I recommend working through the beginner code labs on these subjects, then try doing it with your own project and coming back here if you have more specific questions. However I will say, ultimately ListAdapter is much better than Adapter…

Comment: because you don’t have to worry about the various `notify…` functions and can simply pass new lists for it to handle automatically, with animations and everything. But you must have a very firm grasp of object oriented concepts about references, instances, and equality to be able to use it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't see any new activity here so i will just drop a code examples so ppl who might encounter this question have some clue for start doing research of their own.

In the fragment where you have your recycler view you might set a listener for fragment result from specific child fragment using a TAG.

This is an example of mine:

```
childFragmentManager.setFragmentResultListener(
            VisitanteVehiculoFormDialog.TAG,
            viewLifecycleOwner
        ) { key, bundle ->
            val result =
                bundle.getSerializable(VisitanteVehiculoFormDialog.TAG_RESULT) as VisitanteVehiculoSerializale
            _visitanteVehiculoAdapter.insertItem(
                AutomovilVisitante(
                    1,
                    MODELO = result.MODELO,
                    PLACA_TEXTO = result.PLACA_TEXTO,
                    ID_VISITANTE_AUTORIZADO = result.ID_VISITANTE_AUTORIZADO,
                    ID_AUTOMOVIL_VISITANTE = result.ID_AUTOMOVIL_VISITANTE
                )
            )
```

In my dialog fragment i have the following:

```
 binding?.buttonCrearVisitanteAutomovil?.setOnClickListener {
            val b = Bundle()
            b.putSerializable(
                TAG_RESULT, VisitanteVehiculoSerializale(
                    MODELO = binding?.etModeloVehiculo2?.text.toString(),
                    PLACA_TEXTO = binding?.etPlacaVehiculo?.text.toString(),
                    ID_VISITANTE_AUTORIZADO = 0,
                    ID_AUTOMOVIL_VISITANTE = 0
                )
            )
            Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
                setFragmentResult(TAG, b)
                dismiss()
            }, 1000L)
        }
```

hope someone find this examples useful.

Comment: Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed() is optional i just want to prevent an user from flooding his own screen.